# Height of dynamic content in jQuery-mobile accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and kbw.countdown (from https://github.com/kbwood/countdown) and having an issue when the countdown is displayed in any but the last accordian section, the accordian headers sit on top of the output.

I've got a minimal jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/kgfullerton/AFcZM/ which shows the issue - the countdown in Section 2 is how I'd also like it to look in Section 1 - I'm guessing it's an issue that the content is set after the page is created and the height of the accordian section is fixed somehow - wondered if anyone has come across this in the past - is there a better place than DOMLoad/DOMContentReady to put the following to start the countdown displaying

```
$(function(){
    $('#countdownOne').countdown({until: new Date(2029,1,1)});
    $('#countdownTwo').countdown({until: new Date(2029,1,1)});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution, but certainly a workaround that solves the display issue:

Just add a bottom margin to the DIV surrounding your countdown spans.

```
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="d">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div class="botMargin"> 
                <span id="countdownOne"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

       .botMargin {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/AFcZM/1/

Comment: Brilliant, that certainly solves the issue for me, and it's a reasonable clean/readable fix - accepting this as it solves the issue and was via CSS which I was expecting :)